# Is is possible to add button that will redirect to other page?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I want to add buttons next to items, which will redirect to my other project in order to sign items (files). We have successfully completed forge API project (3legged), that will work at some web address. But customer decided that to type url on browser is external work for users who work on a construction site, so they are asking to add buttons for each file item in the Document Management (bim360)
 Image - [sign button next to items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbMAd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, BIM360 Document Management didn't support adding external items or other customizations on its pages currently, you have to make your own web site integrated with Forge APIs for that propose.